# MSVC - expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "float" on generic array?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, typedef, implicit-conversion

MSVC on Visual Studio 2019 says "expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "float" on generic array" here:

```
void _stdcall sample::Eff_Render(PWAV32FS SourceBuffer, PWAV32FS DestBuffer, int Length)
{
    float gain = _gain;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < Length; ii++)
    {
        (*DestBuffer)[ii][0] = (*SourceBuffer)[ii][0] * gain;
        (*DestBuffer)[ii][1] = (*SourceBuffer)[ii][1] * gain;
    }
}
```

the problem seems here:

```
    (*DestBuffer)[ii][0] = (*SourceBuffer)[ii][0] * gain;
    (*DestBuffer)[ii][1] = (*SourceBuffer)[ii][1] * gain;
```

Not sure why:

```
typedef float TWAV32FS[2];
typedef TWAV32FS *PWAV32FS;
```

Some flag to be disabled? On gcc this kind of "cast" seems auto-manage by the compiler.
What's the correct way to manage this? (maybe I'm wrong on gcc and didn't know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    (*DestBuffer)[ii][0] = (*SourceBuffer)[ii][0] * gain;
    (*DestBuffer)[ii][1] = (*SourceBuffer)[ii][1] * gain;
```

To this:

```
    DestBuffer[ii][0] = (SourceBuffer[ii][0]) * gain;
    DestBuffer[ii][1] = (SourceBuffer[ii][1]) * gain;
```

Explanation:

(I'm guessing you are doing audio processing of a stereo signal in floating point).

`DestBuffer` and `SourceBuffer` are both arrays of samples. Each sample is a pair of floats.

Each sample is referenced like this:

```
DestBuffer[ii]
```

Each individual channel on a sample is referenced like this:

```
DestBuffer[ii][0]
DestBuffer[ii][1]
```

The error you have with this syntax:

```
(*DestBuffer)[ii][0]
```

Is that `*DestBuffer` is really the same as `DestBuffer[0]`, or the first sample in the array. So `(*DestBuffer)[ii]` is the same as `DestBuffer[0][ii]` which is not what you want anyway.  But `(*DestBuffer)[ii][0]` is the same as `DestBuffer[0][ii][0]` - which triggers the compiler error because that third dimension does not exist.

Having done some audio processing code before - don't forget to clamp the result of your multiplication with `gain` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Due to these typedefs

```
typedef float TWAV32FS[2];
typedef TWAV32FS *PWAV32FS;
```

the typedef name `PWAV32FS` is equivalent to `float ( * )[2]`.

So the parameters `SourceBuffer` and  `DestBuffer` actually are declared like

```
float ( *SourceBuffer )[2], float ( * DestBuffer )[2]
```

Thus the for loop should be rewritten like

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < Length; ii++)
{
    DestBuffer[ii][0] = SourceBuffer[ii][0] * gain;
    DestBuffer[ii][1] = SourceBuffer[ii][1] * gain;
}
```